# C# replace item in list<string> "/"

Tags: c#, list, replace, char

I want\need to change specific char with another char inside a list

I want to change "A" with "\P\;"

this is what I have done

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++)
{
    msg[i] = msg[i].Replace("A", "\P\;");
}
```

but I get this error:
"Unrecognized escape sequence"

---

The  problem is that it doesn't change it to HEX after it.

so this is what I have thought to do :

```
List<string> changeOne = new List<string>
for (int i=0;i<msg.Count();i++)
{
if msg[i] == "A" 
{
changeOne[i] = "\";
change[One[i+1] = "p";
}
i++;
}
```

can I do something like this?
how do make it to work?
because i think I will have problems

let say the msg list is this :

```
0-D
1-A
2-S
3-1
```

I want the changeOne list to be like this

```
0-D
1-\
2-p
3-\
4-;
5-S
6-1
```

Thanks ,

Comment: The backslash is an escape character; e.g. for a new line you'd use `"\n"`.  To avoid this you either need to escape the backslash: `"\\"`, or use a non escaped string: `@"\"`; i.e. `"\\P\\;"` or `@"\P\;"`.

Comment: You also use string literals `@"\P\;"` [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim)

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by _"change it to HEX"_ - there does not appear to be any hexadecimal characters in your example

Comment: I know - I thought it will be the same, but now I have change the question - take a look

Comment: You should probably have asked the revised version as a new question, since you have completely changed the nature of your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that your question is not too clear.
You want to replace one string with 4 strings.

```
1-A
```

becomes

```
1-\
2-p
3-\
4-;
```

in your example.

```
List<string> changeOne = new List<string>
for (int i=0;i<msg.Count();i++)
{
   if (msg[i] == "A")
   {
     changeOne.AddRange( new [] {"\\","p","\\",";" });
   }
   else
   {
          changeOne.Add(msg[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: I just read about this and it wan't clear .  its what i want - Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try using `verbatim string literal` - anything in the string that would normally be interpreted as an escape sequence is ignored.

ex : `C:\\Users\\Rich` is the same as `@"C:\Users\Rich"`

[Exemple](https://dotnetfiddle.net/AKRtDV)

In your case:

```
msg[i] = msg[i].Replace("A", @"\P\;");
```

Comment: the problem is that I need to change it to HEX , and if i do with '@' - it doesn't convert it ..

Comment: @David12123 What do you mean by "change to hex"? Maybe you should add this info into your question.

Comment: @David12123 it must work with @, recheck your code to convert to HEX

Comment: I have change my post - please take a look

Comment: @David12123 That changes the question completely, as you actually don´t want to replace a string by another, but a string by up to three and add them into a list.

Comment: so to post a new question ?

Comment: @ThierryV No, it does not work. OP actually wants four elements in the list, one being `"\"`, one being `"P"`, one further for `"\"` and one `";"`. Your solution resuls in `"1-\\P\\;"`, not in `"1", "\\", "P", "\\", ";"`.

Answer (score 2):

When you don't want a literal value escaped in C# you can use the Verbatim String marker.

In this case, replace `"\P\;"` with `@"\P\;"` this is much easier to understand then having multiple escapes in a string.

Answer (score 0):

The backslash ("\") character is a special escape character you need to use two backslashes or use the @ verbatim string.

```
for (int i = 0; i < msg.Count; i++)
        {
            msg[i] = msg[i].Replace("A", "\\P\\;");
            //or
            msg[i] = msg[i].Replace("A", @"\P\;");
        }
```

You can refer to this link : [Escape Sequences](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h21280bw.aspx)

Comment: I have change my post - please look